# Throughput calculation of a simulation in UnetStack using trace.json file

Tags: unetstack

I'm developing a `trace analyzer tool` for `UnetStack`. My tool can determine `TxCount`, `RxCount`, and `end-to-end delay` for each successfully received packet by using a simulation's trace.json file. Next, I want to calculate the `throughput`. How do I do that?
Is there enough data in the `trace.json` file to calculate `throughput`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many different definitions for throughput, depending on which layer traffic you're looking at. The tracer included with UnetStack computes throughput at the PHY layer, by measuring the total amount of time that a node is busy receiving successful frames normalized by the total amount of simulation time x number of nodes.

You could do the same by looking at the `RxFrameNtf` entries in `trace.json`, but will need additional information such as CONTROL and DATA frame duration from your simulation settings in order to complete the computation, as this information is not published in the `trace.json` in the current version (3.x) of UnetStack.

The relevant information is currently more easily available from `trace.nam`.

P.S. We may expose the duration information in a later version of UnetStack.

Comment: following is the modem configuration used in my simulation  -> ```channel.model = ProtocolChannelModel  // use the protocol channel model```  ```modem.dataRate = [2400, 2400].bps  // arbitrary data rate```  ```modem.frameLength = [2400/8, 2400/8].bytes   // 1 second worth of data per frame```  ```modem.headerLength = 0       // no overhead from header```  ```modem.preambleDuration = 0    // no overhead from preamble```  ```modem.txDelay = 0   // don't simulate hardware delays``` please let me know with is information, how throughput can be calculated

Comment: while going through the unet-handbook I get to know that frameDuration for CONTROL is  0.95 and frameDuration for DATA is 0.7. considering this information and RxFrameNtf entries in trace.json, how I will calculate the throughput? or how I will measure the total amount of time that a node is busy receiving successful frames?

Comment: With the config shown in your comment above, your CONTROL/DATA frame duration is 1 second. So each `RxFrameNtf` represents 1 second of successful channel use. Normalized throughput would then be the number of `RxFrameNtf` x 1 second / total simulation time.

Comment: thank you so much, sir. It was beneficial.